# Google App Engine: "We can not locate data file'

Tags: google-app-engine

I am a beginner with google app engines.  My goal is to port an existing webpage to GAE.  The difficulty I am having centers around the location of the .js files.  To get it to run on my local machine, I placed  .js files in a static directory with references in the html like

```
<link href="/static/tblDz_Qs_clinical.js"....
```

Everything works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy, I get a message that

```
 'we cannot locate the datafile
 http://dermdudes.appspot.com/static/tblDz_Qs_clinical.js'
```

Here is the main.py:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=False)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('DD_querydriven2.html')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

here is the app.yaml:

```
application: dermdudes
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

here is the reference in the html that is triggering the message:

```
<link href="/static/tblDz_Qs_clinical.js" type="application/json" rel="exhibit/data" />
```

If I can only get GAE to find the .js files then everything will be perfect.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You get a message where? In your HTTP response? In your logs? Via carrier pigeon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psychic debugging: Case sensitive files name?, make the filename lowercase and change the reference to be lower case also.